# why just when i add log to the try block, i can see it at the output file?

Tags: java, logging

i tried to provide an logger file output and i saw that only one line is showed at the output file - only the one that inside the try catch block, the others are just at the console

attached here my code for test

```
public class Something {

Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
FileHandler fh;

@BeforeEach
public void wallad() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}

@AfterEach
public void asddf() {
    System.out.println("pizza");
}

@Tag("test")
@Test
public void some() {

    try {
        fh = new FileHandler("C:\\MyLogFile.txt");
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "severe");------->only these  
                     will show at the output file
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST);
    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        logger.addHandler(handler);
        logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

    System.out.println("test1");
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "warning");
    System.out.println("test2");
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "information");
    System.out.println("test3");
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "severe");
    System.out.println("test4");

    logger.log(Level.FINEST, "finest");
    System.out.println("test5");
    logger.log(Level.FINE, "fine");
    System.out.println("test6");
    logger.log(Level.FINER, "finer");
    System.out.println("test7");
    logger.log(Level.FINEST, "finest");

}
}
```

how can i take out all the log file? there is no way that it need to be inside the try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new `ConsoleHandler` with `ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();` which is good. You're also calling `logger.addHandler(handler)` which will *add* this `ConsoleHandler` to the logger.

This *would* also have a `FileHandler` if it were not for the fact that you just reinstantiated the `logger` variable with:

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
```

Simply remove this line and your `logger` will both have a `FileHandler` and `ConsoleHandler`.

Comment: just for curious, what these line do?

    logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());

Comment: It recreates your `logger` object, your `logger` object *already* had been created and you had added the `FileHandler` handler to that.  But that line turned `logger` into a new object to which the `FileHandler` had not been added.

Comment: i can do these all on the logger without adding new handler?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that

Comment: assume that i use only the logger, why i create a new handler for writing to file?


            logger.setLevel(Level.FINEST); --->setting level
     ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();--->why is that?
     handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
     logger.addHandler(handler);
     logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

i understand that after these the logger takes the log from the handler but why the logger it self can not do it with all the levels?

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what you mean

Comment: why do i create the handler? the logger can not write to file without the console handler?
also what is the line  logger.setUseParentHandlers(false) do?

Comment: Ah I get it, you do not have to add a console handler at all if you only want to write to the file. The console handler prints your messages to the console, by adding both the file handler and a console handler each message is written to the file *and* the console.

Comment: the messages will write to the console and the file - all of them it needs to say.
and these line
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
what she does?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the handler to be ConsoleHandler, you no longer write to file,

```
ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
```

Delete this line to continue writing to your file

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
```

Comment: only one line, the first that you mention